# Mosquitto_pub/sub can not connect to mosquitto broker via TLS

Tags: tls1.2, mosquitto

I am doing some tests on Windows, although the target system will be raspbian. Mosquitto version is 2.0.15.
For the moment I am NOT using a user/password, so I have not set a password file in the conf file, and I have allowed anonimous connection.
Here is how I have proceeded:

- Created all the certificate/key stuff according to Steve's indications as in
  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/
  , making sure to use the correct host name as "common name", that I will indicate as (hostname) hereafter; gave no extended info for SAN;
- Put ca.crt, server.crt and server.key into a "certs" folder under the mosquitto folder, for use by the broker;
- Put ca.crt into a "client" folder under the mosquitto folder, for use by clients;
- Set mosquitto conf file (see below), restarted the mosquitto service;
- Tested the certificate: `openssl verify -CAfile 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt' 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt'` it says "OK"
- Tested an openssl connection: `openssl s_client -connect (hostname):8883 --CAfile 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt'` the connection was established, although among the abundant output I have noticed a weird message: Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate); looks good to me, after all I have actually self-signed the certificate;
- Finally, tried a mosquitto_sub command: `./mosquitto_sub -h (hostname) -p 8883 -V 'mqttv311' -i 'subscriber' --cafile 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\client\ca.crt' --insecure -t 'sm/state' -d`,
  but got an error:

  ```
  OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Error: protocol error
  ```

note: option `--insecure` is an attempt to overcome the self-signed certificate warning;

- The mosquitto log file reports: `OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca; 2023-05-08 10:09:22: Client <unknown> disconnected: protocol error.`

The relevant section nof the mosquitto.conf file:

```
#crypted listener
listener 8883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
cafile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Has anyone stumbled in a similar problem? How was it resolved?
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try taking the `tls_version` out of the mosquitto config file, let it negotiate it's own levels.

Comment: Also `openssl verify -CAfile 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt' 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt'` is meaningless as it's only checking the CA cert matches it's self. You need to test the server cert against the CA cert. (also server.crt should container the full ca->server chain)

Comment: @hardillb Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, removing the `tls_version` line has not solved the problem. I have also followed your advice about `openssl verify`, in order to challenge the client certificate againts the server certificate (and viceversa, just for fun), also adding a `-check_ss_sig` option because of the self-signed certificates, and the verification fails! I guess there must be something wrong with the certificate/key stuff. I will do some more attempts in that direction. Will let you know.

Comment: @hardillb I tried re-generating all the certificate/key stuff by following the slightly more elaborate tutorial of haibac: https://bacnh.com/how-create-self-signed-certificates, but keep getting the error. Apparently, self-signed certificates don't work in this context. I give up.